# MVC Model Binding not binding simple object on nested loops

Tags: asp.net-mvc, binding, model-binding

Having this structure:

Index.cshtml:

```
@foreach (var category in Model) {
    @Html.DisplayFor(m => category.Products)
}
```

Products.cshtml:

```
...
@Html.Partial("_AddToCartProductViewModel", new CheckoutVC.Models.ModelView.AddToCartProductViewModel(Model))
...
```

_AddToCartProductViewModel.cshtml :

```
@model CheckoutVC.Models.ModelView.AddToCartProductViewModel
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("AddToCart", "Cart", new AjaxOptions { LoadingElementId = "loading" + Model.IdProduct, OnSuccess = "showMessage", UpdateTargetId = "cart_widget" })) {
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.IdProduct)
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.IdPrescriptionType)
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.PrescriptionRequired)
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Quantity)
    <span class="p-r-s">@Html.LabelFor(m=>m.IdPrescriptionType)</span>
    @Html.DropDownListFor(m=>m.IdPrescriptionType, new SelectList(Model.PrescriptionOptions, "Item1", "Item2"), String.Empty) 
    <button class="action add @Html.PrescriptionRequiredCss(Model.PrescriptionRequired)" type="submit">agregar al carrito<img class="loading" id="loading@(Model.IdProduct)" alt="" src="@Url.Content("~/Content/images/shared/loading_16x16.gif")" width="16" height="16" /></button>
}
```

With this AddToCartProductViewModel.cs constructor :

```
public AddToCartProductViewModel(ProductCheckoutMinVO product, int quantity = 1) {
    IdProduct = product.Id;
    PrescriptionRequired = product.PrescriptionRequired;
    Quantity = 1;
    Promotions = product.Promotions;
}

[Required]
[Min(1)]
public int IdProduct { get; set; }

public int Quantity { get; set; }

public bool? PrescriptionRequired { get; set; }

[Min(0)]
public int IdPrescriptionType { get; set; }
```

MVC generate this Request on submit:

```
category.Products[0].IdProduct:826
category.Products[0].IdPrescriptionType:0
category.Products[0].PrescriptionRequired:False
category.Products[0].Quantity:1
category.Products[0].IdPrescriptionType:1
X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest
```

Problem is, my controller CartController.cs :

```
public RedirectToRouteResult AddToCart(AddToCartProductViewModel product, FormCollection form, string returnUrl = null) {
...
}
```

the FormCollection (form) does receive the parameters while the AddToCartProductViewModel (product) does NOT bind.

I have some ideas why properties are not binding to product and how im doing some magic here and there to get a single-object form populated from some nested loops (in which one would expect a collection object in request [one being the framework]), yet cannot find a elegant solution to have this kind of form-scenario bind to AddToCartProductViewModel.

I can make it work 'somehow' using the properties directly into the AddToCart method but then i lose validation (dataannotations) on the modelview.

How can I make MVC bind these properties to the AddToCartProductViewModel view model

Comment: Can you show the complete AddToCartProductViewModel? Especially the public properties?

Comment: done, i have properties with {get; set;}, that's not the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could try:

```
public RedirectToRouteResult AddToCart([Bind(Prefix="category.Products[0]")]AddToCartProductViewModel product, FormCollectionform, string returnUrl = null) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Solving some problem brings up another.
Ended up doing it manually with html tags and leave the data annotations validation out.

*may* be a messed up viewmodel problem i just don't know and don't have the time or resources to make it work as i would like right now. Maybe I'll try to address in the future.

Don't know if there's a way to close the question or what to do? editor feel free to update this as you pleases. :D